# GWT SuperDev Source Code not Showing

Tags: java, maven, gwt, libgdx, gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm following the instructions in this blog post (http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3073) for trying to debug the GWT version of my LibGDX project.

I can compile the GWT project fine, and start the superdev code server using en Eclipse "Run As" profile. I then start Jetty using `mvn verify -Phtml`, browse to `localhost:8080/index.html` and enable dev mode as per the blog post. Something of note is that I don't see the dialog box as described in the post ("GWT modile 'blah' may need to be recompiled").

When looking at sources in Chrome's developer tools, I don't see any of my linked Java source under the localhost:9876 tree node; instead I see something like this:

```
localhost:9876
  projectname
    gwt/chrome
      chrome.css
    {some long MD5-lookign thing}.cache.js
    projectname.nocache.js
```

It's be ace if I could figure out how to see my code linked there and put breakpoints in, as at the moment I'm getting a GdxRuntimeException with a message of "Not implemented" thrown somewhere, but I've no idea from where.

Comment: Did you enable source maps in Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: "Enable JS source maps" was already checked in Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: I think you also have to open the Chrome Developer Tools **before** you load/refresh the page.

Comment: Interestingly it works in Firefox...

Comment: Out of curiosity: which version of GWT are you using?

Comment: Has this been resolved? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I see only GWT sources and Vaadin's. Don't see mine. Is it an issue?

Comment: I have the same problem guys, any solution?